# Jquery .find td with text in th

Tags: jquery

I need set color for TD which containt 1, but only for TH which containt AAA. I have this table and I prepare this script. But script not work. Do you have some idea please ?

Thank very much

**TABLE**

```
<TABLE>
<TR><TH COLSPAN="2">AAA</TH></TR>
<TR>
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD>2</TD>
</TR>
 <TR>
    <TD>A</TD>
    <TD>B</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TH COLSPAN="2">DDD</TH></TR>
<TR>
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD>2</TD>
</TR>
 <TR>
    <TD>A</TD>
    <TD>B</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('tr').each(function(){
var tr = $(this);
if (tr.find('th:eq(0)').text()=="AAA") {
    if(tr.find('td:eq(0)').text()=="1") tr.addClass('hidden');
}
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden{
color:red;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of the way your `<TH>`s are mixed in with your other rows, the simplest solution involves looping through all rows, like this:

```
var lastHeader = '';
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var cells = $(this).find('td,th');
    if (cells.filter('th').size() > 0) { // this is a header row            
        lastHeader = cells.text();
    } else if (lastHeader == 'AAA') { // it's under an AAA section
        cells.filter(':contains(1)').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

You can see an example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/kapvr/

I took a bit of a shortcut in the above script to add the class to any cells that **contain** the text `1` - even if there's more content as well. If you want an exact match, you could modify it like this:

```
var lastHeader = '';
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var cells = $(this).find('td,th');
    if (cells.filter('th').size() > 0) { // this is a header row            
        lastHeader = cells.text();
    } else if (lastHeader == 'AAA') { // it's under an AAA section
        cells.each(function() {
            if ($(this).text() == '1') $(this).addClass('hidden');
        });
    }
});
```

That version can be seen in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/5ybPp/

Comment: Thank very much. This is good. I have only one question. If I need  set background-color for whole TR wiht TD which containt 1 and TH which containt AAA. Css class will be background-color:red; . I know it.

Comment: @user2439317 If you actually make sure you understand the code samples I gave above, it should be pretty simple to modify them to update the parent `<tr>` instead of the `<td>` itself. Something like `x.closest('tr')` will find the first parent `<tr>` element of the element referred to  by the variable `x`.

Answer (score 1):

The body of your each loop looks at a single `tr`, trying to find both `th` and `td` there, but in your HTML the `th` and `td` are not in the same row. You'll need to look for the `th` in `tr.prev()` or look for the `td` in `tr.next()`.

Comment: You can write me whole script please?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would change the markup to make this easier.

```
<TABLE>
<TR><TH COLSPAN="2">AAA</TH></TR>
<TR>
    <TD class="hidden">1</TD>
    <TD>2</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>A</TD>
    <TD>B</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TH COLSPAN="2">DDD</TH></TR>
<TR>
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD>2</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>A</TD>
    <TD>B</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

With this altered markup, you don't need the script at all.

How are you getting the HTML in this case?